# Trying to find language written on item

Tags: written-language, language-identification

I have an item that has text on it, written in a different language. Ive been doing research trying to find it or something similar, but no luck. Anyone know what it says or the language? Much appreciated thank you

[full picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGqGg.jpg)

[image: one part, reversed]

Answer (score 6):

It is Amharic, and the picture is upside down. The items below (at the top of your picture, between horizontal bars) are numerals.

Comment: If you have an Ethiopian font installed, the readable part of the text reads...ማቂ፡ኃያለ //፲፱፻፩፫ , the word ኃያለ meaning “almighty” according to Google translate, ant the numerals ፲፱፻፩፫ being 1913 (which probably to 1920-1921 AD)

Comment: Actually, i think it's ማዊ ኃይለ, _mawi hayle_, which is part of  ቀዳማዊ ኃይለ ሥላሴ _qädamawi haylä səllasé_, the full name of Emperor Haile Selassie. I'm not suggesting that his name appears on the vessel, but at least one and probably two elements of his name do. My guess is that they are the name of somebody else. According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haile_Selassie), "Haile Selassie" means "power of the Trinity", but I haven't found what "Qedamawi" means. A later ruler of Ethiopia was called Haile Maryam Mengistu ("Power of Mary")